# Trying to pull Max date less than Date on the row

Tags: business-objects

I know this is a tough one but I'm basically trying to say. Give me a service call and its completion date, then give me the Max date for all service calls where the date is less than the date of the service call I'm inquiring about.

Basically the end result I'm looking for is to say was there another service call on this piece of equipment that was within the last 30 days.

So as you can see in the image for say Asset 50698 service call 579032 we have a date of 11/9/2020 the call below that was 10/22/2020 which was less than 30 days. I want to somehow find a way to count how many service calls I have where this has occurred. Is this possible?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a context operator `In`, `ForEach` or `ForAll` (`in` in this case)

Add a variable "MaxAssetDate" and assign it a Formula similar to the following based on your column headers.

`=Max([Service Call Completion Date] In ([Asset ID];[Service Call])) In (Asset ID])`

Then add this as a column.  Provided you have a prompt filtering for a given asset or "date" this column will then show the max date for each service call of the same asset ID.  Then add a new variable: ServiceCallDaysDiff: Then by using DatesBetween() with "MaxAssetDate" and ServiceCallCompletionDate and DayPeriod; `=DatesBetween([ServiceCallCompletionDate];[MaxAssetDate];DayPeriod)` you should get a number 0-X.  Then add a filter based if the number is between 1 and 30 then you show those records, otherwise hide the rest; or do whatever logic is then needed.

Now if you're dealing with hundreds of thousands of records this isn't ideal as you're putting all the processing on the webi engine when it ideally would occur as an object in the database layer.   However if you only have a few thousand records this should be managable.

To add a count of service calls...
add variable: ServiceCallsCount:
`=Sum(Sum(If([ServiceCallDaysDiff]=0;0;1)) In ([AssetID]))`

this will count the non zero day differents.  Note this will extend beyond 30 so if you want to limit by 30 days adjust the if statement to zero out those not between 1 and 30.

This is but one approach: there may be simpler ways.